# Issue with specific 301 redirection in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having an issue with a format of URL.

I need to send 
/en
to /

The problem is that I need only /en (exactly), not /en/foo...

I know how to do it with string that ends with .html, but here I have other URLS that have /en/stuff and they are also matched.

Would really appreciate assistance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify end of string in `RewriteCond` e.g.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  / [L,R=301]
```

Please note that Condition pattern as well as Rewrite Rule pattern are a perl compatible regular expression (with some additions):

For Anchors:

- **^** - Start-of-line anchor
- **$** - End-of-line anchor

**EDIT**

BTW, there is very nice *htaccess tester* at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ which you could use to test the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^en/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

This will redirect `/en` or `/en/` to `/` also note that `/EN` will also be handled because of NC (Ignore Case) flag used here.